# Heavy file generated on spooling in unix

Tags: oracle, unix, spool

I run this code from a unix file.
Please Find Below  my code

```
set colsep ,
set heading off
set pagesize 0
set feedback off
set linesize 32767
set trimspool on
set tab off
spool My_File
select * from my_table; /* it has 45 records*/
spool off;
```

Once I run this code, I have my output file generated, but the **columns are seperated with very big spaces and even the records are seperated with big spaces. As a result I get a very huge file.**

Is there any workaround for this ... Thanks in advance..

Comment: This looks like an Oracle sqlldr conf file, yes? If so, use the tag [oracle]. Note there are only 3 followers for `spool` but thousands of followers for Oracle. If not oracle, please use the correct DB tag. Search here for `[oracle] trimspool` and you may luck out find what you need in the first few A:s. Good luck.

Comment: thanks for the sugesssion..

Answer (score 1):

What i do in these situations is not to use colsep and and do the concatenation myself.

```
set heading off
set pagesize 0
set feedback off
set linesize 32767
set trimspool on
set tab off
spool My_File
select column1||','||column2||','||column3.... from my_table;
spool off;
```